# OCR with Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, ocr, image-recognition

I would like to implement a letter detection feature for my "guess the drawing" game in Unity, that would detect if someone draws a letter and I would count it as cheating. So people would only be able to draw the word requested as pictures and would not draw the letters that create word itself.

I would like to know what is your opinion and what technology can I use for this task in Unity3d. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuforia is best pick for your requirement.

You can download vuforia SDK for unity from below link.

https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk

Steps need to be followed:

1.Download SDK for unity.
2.Draw the patters which you want as answers in any of tools like paint or photoshop and take screenshots of them.
3.Remove main camera and add AR camera in prefabs folder of vuforia library
4.Drag and drop image targets to your project and add the screenshots you have taken
5.Now implement code to broadcast message if image target is detected.
6.Use this broadcast message to implement post game logic.

There is so much to learn about image recognition and Vuforia, adding image targets and all require few additional steps, You can go through the tutorials for better understanding on how to use Vuforia SDK.

Following is link for vuforia tutorials

https://library.vuforia.com/tutorials

Happy Game Development